# Gather a row of tableB from buttons row of table A

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am working in php and bootstrap with tables.

- I have a tableA that for each row contains a button.
- Each button has a value assigned equal to the row number. (see below)

  ```
  $job_id = $row['id'];
  <td> <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'   name='job_id' value=$job_id  id='job_id'>Info</a></td>
  ```

I cannot achieve this:
- Each button open a modal pop-up that contains the row of a tableB

So if I click on the button of the second row of tableA I want to show in the popup all the data that row2 of the tableB contains and so on.

Basically I cannot find out how to connect the button with a specific row of another table.

1. With this code in my modal I can only gather the entire tableB, but not the single row.

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * from tableb WHERE id=job_id ";
   ```
2. With this code in my modal I gather always the row 3 of tableB for all the buttons...

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * from tableb WHERE id=3 ";
   ```
3. With this code in my modal I gather for every button the last row I inserted

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * from tableb WHERE id='$job_id' ";
   ```

(TableA and TableB are connected with foreign key)
TableB has (id, job_id) with  job_id= id of tableA
TableA has (id)

Any suggestion that can help me with what I want to achieve?

[image]

---

**UPDATE 1** -> File xxx.php containts the script that load TableA and the script that load the Modal pop up

---

*script that load TableA*

```
     <?php
    include("../includes/connection.php");
    if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * from TableA";
    if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
    }
    echo "
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>";
    /* Get field information for all columns */
   ...
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $job_id = $row['id'];
        echo "<form action='' method=post>";
        echo "<tr class='info'>

                    <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
                    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                    <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td> 
                    <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>

                     <td> <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'   name='job_id' value=[$job_id]  >  Info</a></td>
                </tr>";
        echo "</form>";
    }    echo "   </tbody>   </table>";  ?>
```

---

*script that load the modal popup with tableB*

```
 <?php

include("../includes/connection.php");

if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT * from TableB WHERE job_id=$job_id ";
if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
}
echo "
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
/* Get field information for all columns */
while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "
        <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";
}
echo "
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr class='info'>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['paymenttype'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['faktura'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>

    </tr>";}echo "   </tbody></table>";?>
```

Comment: does tableA already contain all of the data that should be displayed in the modal, or does it contain just the id and a few columns and you need to use the id to get the full info from the database to display when the user clicks the button?

Comment: TableA does not contain all of the data I want to display. I want to diplay the data contained in TableB from the button of TableA but relating the button with the respective row. I addedd a picture to make more clear what I would like to achive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` instruction to link your two tables with one single request.

```
// For the third button the SQL request will be :
$sql="SELECT * FROM tableA A  INNER JOIN tableb B ON B.job_id=A.id WHERE B.id=3";
// For the fourth button the SQL request will be : 
$sql="SELECT * FROM tableA A  INNER JOIN tableb B ON B.job_id=A.id WHERE B.id=4";
```

Note that here I use aliases on my request. For instance A is the alias of table A. Thus, A.id is the id column of tableA.

Look at this link for more infos about SQL Joins : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Anyway I need it for all the button not only for the specific button. Should make a loop so that each new row inserted, gets a button with a new value that correspond to the row number of the tableB

Answer (score 1):

To get the rows in tableB corresponding to an id of tableA you should write:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tableb WHERE job_id = $jobId ";
```

Note that I put 'WHERE job_id = ', and not 'WHERE id = '.

There's an answer that recommends a JOIN. With a JOIN you'll get the row in tableA and the data in tableB

Comment: With this solution all the button shows always the same row( the last row inserted in tableB ).

Comment: I think my problem is that the button gets always the value of the last row inserted (which I can display), but for exemple the button of the third row should contain the value 3 and not the value of the button of the last row.

Comment: can you show the code you use to load the view? I need to see the first query you use to show the list of items in tableA

Comment: Since every button gets an auto increment value when the row is inserted, I should be able to say something like: when button is clicked -> show details of tableB IF ""value of the button"="value of customer id" which I do with `$sql = "SELECT * from tableb WHERE $job_id=id "; ` but i cant get why is only showing the last row inserted.